# ¿Qué significan los 2 números en la función float o double de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estaba viendo la documentación de Laravel en la sección de migraciones, para crear un campo float o double, y vi que para cada uno se le entregan 2 números, el segundo creo que es los números decimales que se quieren, pero el primero no tengo idea, aquí un ejemplo:

```
$table->float('amount', 8, 2);
```

o

```
$table->double('amount', 8, 2);
```

¿A que se refieren estos 2 números que debo entregarle a la migración?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues creo que la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-float) es bastante clara: *The float method creates a FLOAT equivalent column with the given precision (total digits) and scale (decimal digits)* que traducido significa que la primera cifra indica la cantidad de dígitos totales del flotante, es decir, para 2 decimales te quedan 6 dígitos para enteros, siendo el total de dígitos 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso significa **la cantidad de números enteros** que tendrá la tabla y **la cantidad de numeros enteros que MYSQL restara al primer parámetro para usarlos como decimales**.

A mi me costo entender esto pero te dejo un ejemplo:

Si escribes $table->float('amount', 8, 2); en la columna amount se guardaran los números con el siguiente formato.

999999.99

Es decir que tienes 6 enteros y 2 decimales.

Si escribes $table->float('amount', 4, 1); en la columna amount se guardaran los números con el siguiente formato.

999.9

Es decir que tienes 3 enteros y 1 decimal.

El formato 6 enteros y 2 decimales es el más popular por eso, puedes escribir solo el nombre de la columna y dejar que Laravel use este formato por defecto

```
$table->double('amount');
```